# Python 3.6, import local vs 3rd party package with same name

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, segment-io

I have done research but I am not able to find a clear solution...
How to import 3rd party package if I have a package with the same name?

**Example:**

Project tree looks like this:

```
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── analytics
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── client.py
└── main.py
```

Content of *analytics/client.py* is simple:

```py
def identify():
    print("local analytics")
```

*analytics/init.py* is one-liner:

```py
from .client import  identify
```

*main.py*

```py
import analytics


analytics.identify();
```

If I run `python main.py` it will write *local analytics* to the output. It's ok.

However, If I install 3rd party package with name *analytics*, e.g.

`pipenv install analytics-python` (https://segment.com/docs/sources/server/python/)

and run `python main.py`, it will write *local analytics* to the output again.

How to run code from 3rd party package?

Answer (score 3):

The point here is that you are running `__init__.py` as a script. When you run a script, Python adds the directory containing the script to the front of `sys.path`, and this globally affects all subsequent imports.

So in order to work with third-party module either you have to rename your local analytics directory or remove the `__init__.py` file so python do not lists it in `sys.path`.

Comment: Nope. It will import same package as before and assign an alias.

Comment: @KlikKliković , I have updated the answer. Check if it helps.